# Typing space after NSLog(@" makes the screen scroll down and up

Tags: xcode, space, nslog

In xcode, when I type

> `NSLog(@"blar`<kbd>Space</kbd>

the screen scrolls down and up. (I'm trying to type out `NSLog(@"blar blar");`)

However, if I close the quotes first

> `NSLog(@"")`

and then go back and fill in `blar blar` then all is well.

How do I solve this problem? I'm using 2011 macbook pro and OSX Lion and xCode 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know But i'm having the same problem in One class if i ever hit space the page try to scroll up and if Im at the bottom of the page it scrolls up and down making a very boring giggle. But wirdly it's bounded to only one class to which i Changed the Name manually... wonder if that can be it.